# Symfony 4 Validator - Auto logout if invalid

Tags: php, symfony, validation

I wanted to validate my User Object ($user) with the Symfony Validator and return a JsonResponse ($response) if the form input data is valid / is not valid.
But I have the issue that I get logged out automatically when the data could not be validated. I have to login again and this is not the behaviour I expect when some data ist not valid. I found a workaround (see comments below) but this is not very satisfying :/

Here is the method of my Controller:

```
 /**
 * Update user profile data
 *
 * @Route("/api/users/updateprofile")
 * @Security("is_granted('USERS_LIST')")
 */

public function apiProfileUpdate(ValidatorInterface $validator, FlashMessageBuilder $flashMessageBuilder)
{
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    // Prepare Response
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData([]);
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $oldName = $user->getName();
    $oldEmail = $user->getEmail();

    $user->setName($request->request->get('name'));
    $user->setEmail($request->request->get('email'));

    $errors = $validator->validate($user);
    if (count($errors) > 0) { // if this -> auto logout
        $user->setName($oldName); // if I set the both attributes back to the old value
        $user->setEmail($oldEmail); // then I don't get logged out automatically but this is just a workaround and not satisfying
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); // forgot to remove this
        $entityManager->persist($user); // and this line, this is actually deleted in the real code

        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            $errorMessage = $error->getMessage();
            $errorField = $error->getPropertyPath();
            $flashMessageBuilder->addErrorMessage($errorMessage, $errorField);
        };

        return $response;
    }

    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entityManager->persist($user);
    $entityManager->flush();

    $flashMessageBuilder->addSuccessMessage("Success!");
    return $response;
}
```

Sorry for my bad english and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are persisting the User Object even if there are errors in validation, which can cause the problem with the logout.

Try to update ONLY in case there is no validation error:

```
public function apiProfileUpdate(ValidatorInterface $validator, FlashMessageBuilder $flashMessageBuilder)
{
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();

    // Prepare Response
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData([]);

    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $user->setName($request->request->get('name'));
    $user->setEmail($request->request->get('email'));

    $errors = $validator->validate($user);
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $flashMessageBuilder->addSuccessMessage("Success!");
        return $response;
    }

    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        $errorMessage = $error->getMessage();
        $errorField = $error->getPropertyPath();
        $flashMessageBuilder->addErrorMessage($errorMessage, $errorField);
    };

    return $response;
}
```

But I think you should not mix API calls and the classical form approach utilizing FlashMessages, instead return a proper JSON result.

So consider to change the code accordingly:

```
public function apiProfileUpdate(ValidatorInterface $validator, FlashMessageBuilder $flashMessageBuilder)
{
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();

    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $user->setName($request->request->get('name'));
    $user->setEmail($request->request->get('email'));

    $errors = $validator->validate($user);
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return new JsonResponse(['success' => true]);
    }

    $data = [];
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        $data[$error->getPropertyPath()] = $error->getMessage();
    };

    return new JsonResponse(['success' => false, 'errors' => $data], 400);
}
```

Now your calling code can handle a 200 result (success) and the error case with status code 400 and display the error messages for all failed fields from the **errors** part in the result body.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to remove the persisting, I just put it there in order to find out if this prevents the logout issue but it does not.
The Flash Messages will automatically be returned inside of the JsonResponse (i created an Event Listener).

Comment: Okay, in that case please check if you have turned on **logout-on-user-change**, see https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#logout-on-user-change 
Or maybe you ran into that bug: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/28072

Comment: Thank you - i have set the logout_on_user_change to false now this solved the issue. But Symfony says setting it to false is deprecated - should I be worried in terms of security?

Comment: I assume that it has to do with either your UserProvider or your firewall setting. In my app (using Symfony 4.1.6) I don't get logged out when changing the current users data (username / email). I don't have logout_on_user_change, so its true by default. Thats why I initially thought it has to do with your persisting.